# Filtered view of the data in one Google spreadsheet affecting the integrity of the data in dependent Google spreadsheets?

Tags: spreadsheet, google-docs

Good morning smart people,

I have spreadsheet "A" into which someone enters all the data, this sheet is edited, updated and maintained daily.

I then have spreadsheets "B" "C" and "D" that rely on spreadsheet "A" for all or part of their data ( using QUERY and importRange ).

If a 'filter' or 'sort' is temporarily applied to spreadsheet "A" by the person editing the sheet ALL of the dependent sheets receive the filtered data view too and thus breaks all of that sheets calculations and results !!

The filtering or sorting of the data appears to be on the data itself rather than just the "local view" and is therefore being "imported" into all dependent sheets .... is there a better way to do this to prevent "breaking dependent sheets ?

Is it possible to continue to import the "raw" unfiltered data into dependent sheets ?

Answer (score 2):

I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do here, but I'm afraid I have some bad news.

For me (after doing some experiment), **filtering** (assuming that we are doing filter with the Data menu Filter option) does not affect the result of the other sheets. If this is not the case for you, can you please link a demo spreadsheet so we can see your actual problem?

On the other hand **sorting** does affect the other sheets, since it changes the order of the records (=rows) in the table. I don't know any workaround to tell the filter sheet not to respond to the sorting.